# Django display dynamically HTML option depending on whether a checkbox is checked or not

Tags: python, html, django

As I said, I want to display dynamically HTML option depending on whether a checkbox is checked or not
I tried this portion of code :

```
<select id = "productPickerID" name = "product" multiple="multiple" required>
            {% for p in Products%}
                {% if "checked" in mycheckbox.checked %}
                <option value = {{c.productid}}>{{c.productname}}</option>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type = "checkbox" id = "mycheckbox" checked="checked">
```

This code is working well without the if statement so I wonder how I could do that... Maybe use some javascript? or it's possible to do it directly with the templates...
Thanks for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a job for integrating some Javascript into your code.

Python is a server-side programming language and can only manipulate things if done so from the server.

Javascript will be able to do this for you.

```js
function toggle() {
  let checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");
  let text = document.getElementById("text");

  if (checkbox.checked){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="toggle()">
<p id="text" style="display:none">HIDDEN</p>
```